# Flask routing throw 404 on production server

Tags: python, flask

on my production server, my flask application throw 404 when i tried to access www.example.com/admin however, if i tried to access root content, everything works fine. I am using apache for my web server with python 3.4

```
@app.route('/')
def index():
    return render_template("search.html")

. python functions in between
.
.
.


@app.route("/admin")
def admin():
    return render_template("adminAuth.html", error=False)

@app.route("/admin", methods=["POST"])
def adminAuth():
    # Intentionally return None
    return None
```

Remarks: On my test environment, (PyCharm with Flask) everything works fine, I can access /admin

This is my WSGI conf

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
    ServerName NAME
    ServerAdmin admin@mywebsite.com
    WSGIScriptAlias / /path/to/app.wsgi
    <Directory /path/to/webapp/>
        Order allow,deny
        Allow from all
    </Directory>
    Alias /static /path/to/webapp/static
    <Directory /path/to/webapp/static/>
        Order allow,deny
        Allow from all
    </Directory>
    ErrorLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/path/to/error.log
    LogLevel warn
    CustomLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/path/to/access.log combined
</VirtualHost>
```

Comment: Can you post your Apache config on production?

Comment: @mfitzp just posted above.

Comment: Have you installed mod_wsgi ? http://flask.pocoo.org/docs/0.10/deploying/mod_wsgi/